# Where can I find a copy of Dieudonné's 'Infinitesimal Calculus'?

Tags: mathematics, calculus, bourbaki

I found a copy of the French version 'Calcul infinitésimal' online but the English edition seems to only be available on Amazon for a very hefty price, or in American libraries which I do not have access to. If anyone could point me to where I may find this book it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They have copyright laws for a reason. There are websites where you can probably find a pirated pdf copy but they are not exactly legal and we cannot promote them here.

Comment: @Conifold I'm not protesting the copyright, it just seems that the book is out of print and paying $1000 for a new copy on Amazon is just not realistic, leaving the book completely inaccessible.

Comment: [AbeBooks](https://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/infinitesimal-calculus/author/jean-dieudonne/) sells used copies from $48.